# Adding keyboard control to image slider

Tags: javascript

I made my slider to switch slides automatically, but what i should do to make slides changing on left and right arrow? I tried some options, i've watched some turtorials on youtube and i looked into past post but it just doesnt work for me. I will be really greatful if someone help me with this.

Here is my code:

```js
var counter = 1;

setInterval(function(){
  document.getElementById('radio' + counter).checked = true;
  counter++;
  if( counter > 4 ){
    counter = 1;
  }
}, 5000);
```

```html
  <div class="slider">
          <div class="slides">
              <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio1">
              <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio2">
              <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio3">
              <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio4">

              <div class="slide first">
                  <img src="IMG/img1.jpeg" alt="">
                  <div class="text-block">
                      <h1>Specijalna bolnica za bolesti zavisnosti<br>"Dr Boro Lazić"</h1>
                      <p>Prva licencirana klinika za bolesti zavisnosti u Srbiji, osnovana 2003. godine</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="slide">
                  <img src="IMG/img2.jpeg" alt="">
                  <div class="text-block">
                      <h1>"Svako može pobeći iz pakla droge ako se odluči da preuzme prvi veliki korak, zatraži pomoć i prihvati je."</h1>
                      <p>- Betty Ford -</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="slide">
                  <img src="IMG/img3.jpeg" alt="">
                  <div class="text-block">
                      <h1>Who dares, wins!</h1>
                      <p>"Mislila sam da je moj život gotov kada sam došla na kliniku, sada shvatam da je tek počeo."</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="slide">
                  <img src="IMG/img4.jpeg" alt="">
                  <div class="text-block">
                      <h1>"Naš cilj je pronaći odgovarajući finansijsku soluciju za svakog pacijenta kako bi dobio tretman koji zaslužuje"</h1>
                      <p>- Dr Boro Lazić -</p>
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class="navigation-auto">
                  <div class="auto-btn1"></div>
                  <div class="auto-btn2"></div>
                  <div class="auto-btn3"></div>
                  <div class="auto-btn4"></div>
              </div>
          </div>
              <div class="navigation-manual">
                  <label for="radio1" class="manual-btn"></label>
                  <label for="radio2" class="manual-btn"></label>
                  <label for="radio3" class="manual-btn"></label>
                  <label for="radio4" class="manual-btn"></label>
              </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Use javascript and event listeners?